# Bottomsheet showing white background

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Here is sample code to bottom sheet using android jetpack compose
Everything is working fine but it is showing white background.
It should show rounded corner bottom sheet with close button on top right

```
BottomSheetScaffold(
    scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
    sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp,
    sheetElevation = 0.dp,
    sheetGesturesEnabled = false,
     
    sheetContent = {
            },
 sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart =  16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp),
    sheetBackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
    drawerBackgroundColor = Color.Transparent)  

            // Acts as scrim - the semi-transparent dark sheet that covers the rest of    the
            // screen when bottom sheet is opened. 
            if (bottomSheetType != CommonBottomSheetType.None) {
                AnimatedVisibility(
                    visible = bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.isExpanded,
                    enter = fadeIn(initialAlpha = 0.3f),
                    exit = fadeOut(targetAlpha = 1f)
                ) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .alpha(0.9f)
                            .background(Color.Black)
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            // Ignore all taps on the scrim.
                            .pointerInput({}) {}
                    )
                }
            }


    }
```

//sheetElevation = 0.dp, should be 0 because I want to show close button.

[image: Image showing white background]

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
BottomSheetScaffold(
    scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
    sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp,
    sheetElevation = 0.dp,
    sheetGesturesEnabled = false,
    sheetContent = {
        // Your bottom sheet content here
    },
    sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp),
    sheetBackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
    drawerBackgroundColor = Color.Transparent
) {
    // Acts as scrim - the semi-transparent dark sheet that covers the rest of the
    // screen when the bottom sheet is opened.
    if (bottomSheetType != CommonBottomSheetType.None) {
        AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.isExpanded,
            enter = fadeIn(initialAlpha = 0.3f),
            exit = fadeOut(targetAlpha = 1f)
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.3f))
                    // Ignore all taps on the scrim.
                    .pointerInput({}) {}
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I adjusted the `Box` modifier by using `fillMaxSize()` to ensure the scrim covers the entire screen.Also, changed the background color of the `Box` to `Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.3f)` to make it semi-transparent.

Comment: I have tried above suggestion but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

However, it's not clear what the desired UI is you can consider the following points:

1. The white background color is for the inner component so you have to check the "Why you extend your listing?" component to remove the background.
2. If you want the rounded corner shape of the bottom sheet you need to add a background color to the "sheetbackgroundColor" eg. MaterialTheme.colors.background.copy(alpha = 0.3f)
3. Consider using the built-in animation of the bottom sheet instead of the AnimationVisibility

   ```
   BottomSheetScaffold(
   modifier = Modifier // system padding (optional)
       .navigationBarsPadding() 
       .imePadding()
       .displayCutoutPadding(),
   scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
   backgroundColor = if (bottomSheetType != "NONE") Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.9f) else Color.Transparent,
   sheetBackgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.background.copy(alpha = 0.3f),
   sheetElevation = 0.dp,
   sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 8.dp, topEnd = 8.dp),
   sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp,
   sheetContent = {

       Column(Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
           Icon(
               modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 16.dp),
               imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Close,
               contentDescription = "")

           Text(text = "Hello World")
           Text(text = "Hello World")
           Text(text = "Hello World")
           Text(text = "Hello World")
       }
   },
   ```

   ) {}

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjQW7.png)